# Why does the list of reasons to close a question include neither astroturfing nor spam?

Tags: feature-request, closing-questions, close-reasons, spam, self-promotion

I think it would be useful to distinguish between well-intentioned but off-topic questions and those meant to promote a service or advertise a particular product. Is there a way to give advertising its own radio button in the "close" menu?

Comment: Seeing spam like [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2299/cheap-weekends-european-breaks-short-breaks) (hopefully a dead link soon) makes me want to remind people, flag don't downvote.

Comment: What is "astroturfing" in this context?

Comment: "Astroturfing" is a play on "grass-roots support;" it refers to discussion threads started on fora with an ulterior motive, like engendering discussion of a game that is (secretly) produced by the poster.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The flag list includes spam. I think flags are reserved for poor behavior -- there's a qualitative difference between someone who asks a bad question with good intention and someone who's trying to abuse the system, as you note.

Comment: Got it. I hadn't really explored the flag list; I'm finding the features as I stumble over them.

Comment: Can 2000 rep delete spam Bryant?

Comment: I can vote to delete it, but it's only one vote. I believe the big thing that separates moderators from high rep people is that moderators can close/delete/etc. single-handedly.

Comment: If a question is flagged enough it will die automagically.  If you post it here on meta or on chat, we'll usually dog pile it into oblivion.

Answer (score 11):

You should flag spam, not vote to close.

You have a limited number of close votes, don't use them up on spam.

A mod will come and delete things that are flagged and need deleting.